# The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused

Tags: kubernetes

I was able to cluster 2 nodes together in Kubernetes. The master node seems to be running fine but running any command on the worker node results in the error: "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

From master (node1),

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS    AGE       VERSION
node1       Ready     23h       v1.7.3
node2       Ready     23h       v1.7.3
```

From worker (node 2),

```
$ kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated.

On executing,"journalctl -xeu kubelet" I see: 
"CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: Cannot find network namespace for the terminated container", but this seems to be related to installing a pod network ... which I am not able to because of the above error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`kubectl` interfaces with `kube-apiserver` for cluster management. The command works on the master node because that's where `kube-apiserver` runs. On the worker nodes, only `kubelet` and `kube-proxy` is running.

In fact, `kubectl` is supposed to be run on a client (eg. laptop, desktop) and not on the kubernetes nodes.

Comment: so, kubeadm should be on all the nodes and kubectl just on the client system? How do we connect client Kubectl to master then? By, passing ~/.kube/config?

Comment: `kubeadm` is also run on your client machine I believe but I'm not familiar with it. `kubectl` is definitely meant to be run on the client machine. You're right: configure `~/.kube/config` on your client machine to make `kubectl` connect properly to the master node. If you update your question with the config, I can help you with it.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to configure the cluster the way I think is okay for now. But I am running into the same problem today with kubectl running on the master node itself. I was able to run kubectl commands till yesterday and everything was fine. I was in-between trying different template 'kind' and after running ReplicationController template I started get the same error:

{code}
The connection to the server 10.XX.XX.XXX:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
{code}

Comment: There is no ~/.kube/config file as well. Did I configure the system wrong? Everything was working fine before. I am running kubectl version 1.7.3 with Docker 1.12.6.

Comment: Got passed around it by running kubectl init again. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

from master you need ~/.kube/config  pass this file as argument for kubectl command. Copy the config file to other server or laptop then pass the argument as for `kubectl` command

eg:

`kubectl --kubeconfig=~/.kube/config`

Comment: This works for every computer that can access the network, nothing special about the `worker-nodes` . This  should be accepted answer, as the `worker-nodes` in general can't access the kube-api server.

Comment: In worker nodes we can't access kube-api server then how to install network service in worker nodes?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me after executing following commands:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, the message being prompted indicates its related to network.
So one potential answer could also be, which worked for my resolution, is to have a look at the key `cluster` value for `context` within `contexts`.

My error was **that I had placed an incorrect cluster name there**.

Having the appropriate cluster name is crucial to finding it for respective context and the error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`, you may be missing a step.

My Fix:

On MacOS if you install K8s with brew, you still need to `brew install minikube`, afterwards you should run `minikube start`. This will start your cluster.

Run the command `kubectl cluster-info` and you should get a happy path response similar to:

```
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:63000
KubeDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:63308/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Kubernetes install steps: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/

Minikube docs: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

Answer (score 0):

Ensure what context is selected if you're running Kubernetes in the Docker Desktop.

[image: Kubernetes is enabled in Docker Desktop settings]

Once you've selected it right, you'll be able to run the `kubectl` commands without any exception:

```
% kubectl cluster-info                              
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

% kubectl get nodes
NAME             STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready    control-plane,master   2d11h   v1.22.5
```